# sequence of cohomology groups associated to Koszul complex

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the paper "On branched coverings of some homogeneous spaces" of *Kim* and *Manivel* one reads, that there is a *Koszul complex* associated with a section $s$ of a locally free sheaf $S$ of rank $p$ (in terms of Lazarsfeld's book "Positivity in algebraic geometry") of the form:
$$
0 \to \wedge^pS^* \to ... \to S^* \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{J}_{x,X} \to 0,
$$
where $\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{J}_{x,X}$ are all sections, that do not vanish in $x$. 
Let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$. Twisting the complex by $F$ yields
$$
0 \to \wedge^pS^* \otimes F \to...\to S^* \otimes F \to F \to F_x \to 0,
$$
where $F_x$ is the stalk of $F$ in $x$.
In the paper of *Kim* und *Manivel* it is stated, that $F$ is globally generated at $x$ as soon as the cohomology groups
$$
H^i(X,\wedge^iS^* \otimes F) = 0 \qquad \forall i > 0.
$$

A similar argument was used in other papers and it was refered as "by using hypercohomology". Looking up "hypercohomology" doesn't lead to a valid answer. So how does the argumentation behave? Any references?

Comment: The desired result will follow if $H^0(F)\to H^0(F_x)$ is not. This is implied by the vanishing of a certain $H^1$. Now continue to unravel it (which is what hypercohomology does). Let me do this for $p=2$. Let $K$ be the image of $S^*\otimes F\to F$. Then, one wants $H^1(K)=0$. One has a short exact sequence, $0\to \wedge^2 S\otimes F\to S^*\to K\to 0$ and the the vanishing assumptions imply $H^1(K)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, @Mohan.

I've thought about it, but I don't get it exactly. 
To show spannedness, I have to show, that there's a surjective map
$ H^0(F) \to H^0(F_x) \to 0 $, as you said, this is the vanishing of certain $H^1$. 
How can we get certain $H^1$? You let $K$ be the image of $S^*\otimes F \to F$. Where does the exact sequence $0 \to \wedge^2S^* \otimes F \to S^*\otimes F \to K \to 0$ come from? And how do we get a sequence of the form $0 \to K \to F \to F_x \to 0$, which would lead to the surjective map?

Comment: I just split the long exact sequence $0\to \wedge^2S^*\otimes F\to S^*\otimes F\to F\to F_x\to 0$ into two short exact sequences, with $K$ in between.